# How to display an average of Number of views to a user?

Tags: interaction-design, user-research, usability-testing

I would like to show the user that we are giving him an average from 100 to 120

So whats better:

1. more than 100 views?
2. from 100 to 120?
3. ~100?

We have 3 plans and each one has an average number of views.

Keep in mind that we are never less than 100 views in the 1st plan but we might be more than 100 but not by many.

So i thought "more than 100 views" is better but i am afraid that the user will expect way more than 100 views and he will get frustrated.

So What do you think?

Comment: why don't you use the exact number that you have, but differentiate the 3 plans with color coding for example?

Comment: @DimitraMiha No i meant that i have 3 plans

The 1st one: from 100 to 120
The second one : from 1000 to 1200
The third one : from 2000 to 2200

Comment: @Iman Can you specify for what kind of business you are talking because we cannot tell you if users are going to get frustrated when we don't know the domain.

Answer (score 2):

**Number dash number**

**100-120 Views**

This communicates "The number of views between one hundred and one hundred and twenty, which I understand to be what you want to say.